# How to fix: Setting SSIS Execute Package property ExecuteOutOfProcess to True causes error?

Tags: ssis

I have to run packages asynchronously, so I used the ExecuteOutOfProcess property for the first time. As I run into troubles, I decided to make a very basic prototype to reproduce the error in VS 2017/2019:

- Make a project without parameters and connectionmanagers.
- Make a Package Slave with one Expression Task, executing 1==1
- Make a Package Master with a Execute Package Task, point here to Slave and set ExecuteOutOfProcess = True

Slave runs without a problem. Running Master, however, gives these errors:

- Error: Error 0x80040154. Failed to create an instance of empty child package. The Distributed Component Object Model (DCOM) configuration or the installation of SQL Server Integration Services, may be corrupted on your machine.
- Error: Error 0x80040154 while executing package from project reference package "Slave.dtsx". Class is not registrered
  .
- Task Slave failed

I tried this on two different machines, so I can exclude weird configurations. I read about 32/64 bit issues, but I do not use any additional components.

Maybe one of you has a clue how to fix this?

Comment: Did you happen to set the SSIS Transaction property to *required* in the master package? My other theory is that you only have SSDT installed on your machine and the licensing for SSDT only allows for running packages within the context of visual studio. To confirm this, in your Debug menu, attempt to run the Slave package without Debugging (Shift-F5). It it fails, then it's a licensing issue. If it works, then you likely have your references incorrect for the Execute Package Task

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and indeed running Slave outside VS failed: Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 14.0.3002.92 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

Started:  11:34:28
Could not create DTS.Application because of error 0x80040154

Comment: I checked on my one instance, which is VS 2017 Community. On my other instance, however, I run VS 2019 Professional, and I can run Slave outside VS. But Master fails the very same way as on my VS 2017 Community.

Answer (score 0):

I have relatively similar issue.
I'm deploying to 2017 Enterprise server (so I have license to run child packages).
When I leave ExecuteOutOfProcess = False, the child package runs.
When I set ExecuteOutOfProcess = True, the child package fails with this error:

`Value does not fall within the expected range.`

Maybe it's a SQL Server 2017 bug.
The server was recently patched to CU20.